# Is there a way for a getter in C# to cache its result in-line?

Tags: c#, caching, singleton, getter

I've been working on a Discord bot and one of my abstract classes that represents servers ("Bot Contexts") contains the following data.

```cs
public virtual Command[] ContextSpecificCommands { get; } = null;
```

In user-defined Contexts I expect them to override this (if the server that has this code needs to). There's an issue, however, which is that I expect Commands to be singletons in the scope of a Context. This means that `CommandFoo` can exist only once in `CoolContextNumberOne`, and can also exist in `CoolContextNumberTwo` (as a separate instance of `CommandFoo`), but a single context cannot have two instances of `CommandFoo` in it.

My issue comes in with the behavior of getters. If the user does this...

```cs
public override Command[] ContextSpecificCommands => new Command[] {
    new CommandFoo()
};
```

Then this will instantiate `CommandFoo` *every time* ContextSpecificCommands is referenced.

Is there any way to ensure that `ContextSpecificCommands` is cached in-line so that it only instantiates that container array once? I'd like to avoid requiring the user to specify a field and point to that field if possible.

Comment: Well, you can create a field and instantiate it once and return its value: `public override Command[] ContextSpecificCommands => _contextSpecificCommands; // add this field`.

Comment: Yeah, I know about that method. I was trying to avoid this specific method as I want it to be inline only. If its not possible then oh well.

Comment: I've decided to edit my OP to reflect on this.

Comment: This is a typical XY problem. If user has a control over the property and how the underlying object is instantiated then it's up to him/her to decide whether this should be cached or not. One way of solving it is by changing the design. You could introduce a factory class `ContextSpecificCOmmandFactory` and a function `GetContextSpecificCOmmands` that returns the same instance of `Command[]` all the time.

Comment: As it usually is with XY - it is difficult to answer without knowing a lot more details about the problem.

Comment: Given the nature of these comments, and after doing more research, I believe it's safe to assume that what I'm going for is not possible. I'll be writing up an answer for my question momentarily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not natively possible without adding extra code.

In order for a result to cache, a separate backing field must be created and the code must be set up to work with this field.

In order to resolve my dilemma, I have altered my code from:

```cs
// User will override this.
public virtual Command[] ContextSpecificCommands { get; } = null;
```

To:

```
// User will override this.
protected virtual Command[] ContextSpecificCommands { get; } = null;

// These control the cache.
private bool HasPopulatedCommandCache = false;
private Command[] CommandCache = null;

// Things will reference this to get ahold of commands.
public Command[] Commands {
    get {
        if (!HasPopulatedCommandCache) {
            HasPopulatedCommandCache = true;
            CommandCache = ContextSpecificCommands;
        }
        return CommandCache;
    }
}
```

This allows the code to meet all of the goals specified in my original question. The user's class can use an in-line expression to define their commands without the worry of this array being instantiated every time it is referenced.

Comment: Very nice. Note: You don't need `HasPopulatedCommandCache` - if `CommandCache` is `null`, just assign it. And wouldn't a static method variable be useful... :)

Comment: In this case, the cache may be null in legit cases, so using a null comparison will introduce inconsistent behavior. Also, no, a static reference would not be okay -- A command can exist multiple times, it's just limited to a single command object of a specific type *per context*, so two entirely separate contexts can reference one command, and that command will exist separately for each context. It's instance-dependent.

Comment: So it is okay for `ContextSpecificCommands` to return `null`? A static method variable (in a non static method) would be created once per object (a construct C# doesn't have). IOTW, the only difference from your implementation is access to `CommandCache` would be restricted to the `Commands` property `get` method.

Answer (score 2):

This code was for the intellectual exercise, it is not recommended!

If you are willing to force the implementors of your `BotContexts` to use a specific form, then you can insert a type of singleton pattern into the property definition.

Consider:

```
public static class Singleton {
    public static T For<T>(Func<T> makeSingleton) => Singleton<T>.For(makeSingleton);
}

public static class Singleton<T> {
    static Dictionary<Func<T>, T> Cache = new Dictionary<Func<T>, T>();

    public static T For(Func<T> makeSingleton) {
        T singleton;
        if (!Cache.TryGetValue(makeSingleton, out singleton)) {
            singleton = makeSingleton();
            Cache[makeSingleton] = singleton;
        }

        return singleton;
    }
}
```

Now you can use this like so:

```
public class CoolContextNumberOne : BotContexts {
    public override Command[] ContextSpecificCommands => Singleton.For(() => new Command[] { new CommandFoo() });
}

public class CoolContextNumberTwo : BotContexts {
    public override Command[] ContextSpecificCommands => Singleton.For(() => new Command[] { new CommandFoo() });
}
```

Each CoolContext will create one instance of `CommandFoo` regardless of how many times `ContextSpecificCommands` is called.

Since in C# the use of a `new` expression will always generate a new object, it is difficult (impossible?) to see how you could have the code the same and figure out when to generate a new object and when to return an existing object (e.g. if a `Command` was actually a proxy object). If you didn't mind a dependency on optimization being enabled, `StackFrame` and `GetILOffset` could help, but would probably fail in debug mode. And be very brittle.

It may be possible to hide the use of `Singleton` in the types of `Command`s by using `dynamic` and `Expando` but that seems like an even worse idea.

Comment: Certainly an interesting implementation! I'll have to keep it in mind, of course, keeping in mind what you said about it not being very practical :P